# RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the rolling price slope of btc trading data (minute data) using pandas. When I run the script, the following error / warning pops up

> sys:1: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned

The url from where I fetch the data is
https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/monthly/klines/BTCUSDT/1m/BTCUSDT-1m-2021-01.zip

The rolling price slope is calculated as follows (time period is 30):

```
result['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(result['Open Time']).map(dt.datetime.toordinal)

for index, data in result.iterrows():

    price_slope = np.polyfit(result['date_ordinal'][index-time_period:index+1],result['Close'][index-time_period:index+1],1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many data, or the degree of your function is very high, or etc.

If you can't solve the problem you can avoid it with :

import warnings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To disable the warning:

```
import warnings    
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', np.RankWarning)
```

Found it at https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html